# Â Always comes When converting from iso-8859-1 to utf-8. Latin Capital Letter a with Circumflex (Â) always comes along with §

Tags: sql, python-3.x, unix, unicode, oracle11g

Consider below steps

`vi tgh.sql`

copy below content into the file `select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'§' from dual` and save the file

now check the unicode format of this file `file -i tgh.sql`. You will see output as below `tgh.sql: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`

Now convert it to utf8 using below command  `iconv  -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 tgh.sql -o tghconv.sql`

Lets check the format of this new file `file -i tghconv.sql` , you will see output as below `tghconv.sql: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

But if you cat this new file you will see completely different result

`cat tghconv.sql`

You will see output as below

`select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'Â§' from dual`

We see an extra `Â` in the output . This was never there initially when we created the file. I do understand that utf-8 hex code for `§` is `xC2A7` and in utf-16 hex code for `§` is `x00A7` and hex code for `Â` is `x00C2` so the conclusion that I can make is that file is somehow getting converted to utf-16 format. How can I avoid this? I am expecting my output to be as below even after converting to ut-8
`select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')||'§' from dual`
Any suggestion?

**Another update to code**
Considering issue might be with my keyboard I slightly changed the test approach above, further details are below

`vi tgh.sql`

copy below content into the file `select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY')||unistr('\00A7') from dual` and save the file

Execute the above sql file using oracle sqlplus as below

```
_resultset=$(sqlplus -s username/password@TNSAliasnameforDB <<EOF
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode
whenever oserror exit sql.sqlcode
set heading off feedback off linesize 32736 trimspool on termout off tab off pagesize 0 long 100000 longc 100000;
spool tgh.out;
@tgh.sql
/
spool off;
EXIT
EOF
)
```

Now lets open the output file `tgh.out`.

`cat tgh.out` Running this we will get output as `03-AUG-2022Â§`. Again the result is same we have an additional `Â` in the output. If we verify the unicode format ( by running command `file -i tgh.out`) of file we will see it as `utf-8`.

Comment: `Â` appears if UTF-8 encoded text is accidentally interpreted as ISO-8851-1 (or a similar ISO encoding). Your terminal is obviously configured for ISO-8851-1. So it cannot correctly display UTF-8 encoded text. I can see that this causes quite some confusion. But what is the real problem you want to solve?

Comment: Yes the issue was with terminal. Terminal encoding format was something else and was causing confusion.  How can I change LINUX terminal encoding format?

Comment: Typically, you change it by setting `LANG` and `LC_ALL` environment variables in `~/.profile`: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. Details depend on your specific Linux system.

Comment: https://benjamin-schweizer.de/unix-terminals-surviving-the-encoding-hell.html . Here author has more explanation on the same line what @Codo had explained above.